# Uncaught Error: Class "Phalcon\Debug" not found

Tags: php, debugging, phalcon

I need to update from PHP 7.3 to PHP 8.0 or PHP 8.1.

About composer.json
php from ~ 7.3.0 to ^ 8.0,
ext-phalcon from ^ 3.3.0 to 5.0.0 beta3
I think I have to update to

I updated and started it
I was able to use it until now
$ debug = new \ Phalcon \ Debug ();
$ debug-> listen ();
Was not usable.

I got the following error.

> Uncaught Error: Class "Phalcon\Debug" not found in

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the Phalcon classes had namespace changes in the change from Phalcon 3 to Phalcon 4, and then some more namespace changes were made from Phalcon 4 to Phalcon 5.

In your specific case, `Phalcon\Debug` has been moved to `Phalcon\Support\Debug`.

You can read about the changes in the documentation [here](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/upgrade) for the upgrade from 3 to 4, and [here](https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/upgrade) for the upgrade from 4 to 5.

Since you are doing such a big jump forward, there may be a lot of changes required.